# SQLite - Update column of the same table, based on result from row_number()

Tags: sqlite

After several tries, I was able to generate a `row_number()` column with the value I wished.

```
select "order", row_number() over win - 1, type, title, body, searched_string from plain_note 

WINDOW win AS (
    order by 
        title desc,
        case when type = 0 then body else searched_string end desc
)
```

[image]

Now, I would like to overwrite entire **"order"** column, with the value from **"row_number() over win - 1"**

For instance,

- In the 1st row, I would like to update **"order"** column (original value 13) with value 0.
- In the 2nd row, I would like to update **"order"** column (original value 14) with value 1.
- ... and so on.

**May I know, what is the correct SQLite statement to do so? Thanks.**

---

The approach I had tried so far is

```
update plain_note set "order" = (
    select row_number() over win - 1 from plain_note 

    WINDOW win AS (
        order by 
            title desc,
            case when type = 0 then body else searched_string end desc
    )
);
```

However, this will make **ALL** rows of "order", having the 1st row of **"row_number() over win - 1"** value, which is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is missing a link between the table's rows and the subquery's rows.
I would write the update method like this:

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over win - 1 as rn from plain_note

  window win as (order by 
    title desc,
    case when type = 0 then body else searched_string end desc
  )    
)
update plain_note set "order" = (select rn from cte where "order" = plain_note."order");
```

This will work of the values in the column `"order"` are unique.